# Breakpoints not hit in view/cshtml files after upgrade to v16.6.2?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net-core, visual-studio-2019

I've been running VS 2019 for awhile now with no problems.  I've been working on the same 2 solutions for the last year with no problems.  Friday I upgraded to the latest version (16.6.2) because VS suggested I should. As soon as I did that, breakpoints in any MVC views no longer function in my project.

I have gone through the standard checklist of the old "No symbols have been loaded for this document" message. I have confirmed that the PDB files are in the right place, that the DLL and PDBs are of the same version, etc. Everything is exactly the same setting-wise as its always been.  Friday morning it worked. 
I installed the latest update (v16.6.2) and now the same breakpoint I had working a few hours before no longer works. Within this same project I CAN set a breakpoint in a controller or other classes - it seems to only be the .cshtml pages that are the problem.

My assumption is that one of 2 things occurred here: either v16.6.2 introduced a new setting I need to change in order for this to work, or v16.6.2 broke it.  I have scoured the webs looking for any settings changes in this release and have come up empty.  I have done the standard machine restart and all that stuff.  No dice there either.

Are there any other troubleshooting steps I have missed?